# Unable to Deploy dashboard to a SharePoint site using dashboard designer sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

when we try to deploy a dashboard to SharePoint site I faced below issue, but other sites in the same web application have no issue.

an error has occurred attempting to contact the specified SharePoint site, please check your connection and settings.
in Ulos logs I saw below errors for the master page.
[image]

[image]